# VB.Net Menuitem added dynamically not firing click event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, onclick, menuitem

I am completely lost here. I have dynamically created a menuitem. I've added an onclick-event handler, but this code never seems to fire. I remember it working a few months back and don't recall making any changes to it, but it's possibly something stupid that I've done.

Please see my code below:

```
frmMain._mnuSep1_0.Visible = True
Dim tlRecentApp As New ToolStripMenuItem(strMenuCaption)
tlRecentApp.Text = "Test"
tlRecentApp.Name = "AddApp"
tlRecentApp.Tag = strMenuID
RecentAppID = strMenuID
AddHandler tlRecentApp.Click, AddressOf Test
frmMain.mnuApplicantS.DropDownItems.Add(tlRecentApp.ToString)
```

The code for the Event:

```
Public Sub MnuRecentApp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ' MsgBox(sender.tag.ToString)
    ApplicantID = sender.tag.ToString
    frmApplicantEdit.Show()
End Sub
```

It gets created but when I click on it nothing happens:

Comment: In your code, you are assigning the method `Test` as the handler of the Click event, try changing it at this line `AddHandler tlRecentApp.Click, AddressOf Test`

Comment: You need to provide more info or better a working example. What are *_mnuSep1_0, strMenuCaption, strMenuID, RecentAppID, mnuApplicantS*? We can not just guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the code for the event handler is

```
Public Sub MnuRecentApp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ' MsgBox(sender.tag.ToString)
    ApplicantID = sender.tag.ToString
    frmApplicantEdit.Show()
End Sub
```

then this line

```
AddHandler tlRecentApp.Click, AddressOf Test
```

should be

```
AddHandler tlRecentApp.Click, AddressOf MnuRecentApp
```

Comment: Hi, yes (apologies for not changing it), you are correct, I was fiddling to try and get it to work. Originally it was AddressOf MnuRecentApp, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to change too much of your code I've tested the following successfully:

**Control**:

```
Dim tlRecentApp As New ToolStripMenuItem(strMenuCaption)
'tlRecentApp.Text = "Test"  This isn't needed as it's done on the above line when declared
tlRecentApp.Name = "AddApp"
tlRecentApp.Tag = strMenuID
RecentAppID = strMenuID
AddHandler tlRecentApp.Click, AddressOf MnuRecentApp
frmMain.mnuApplicantS.Items.Add(tlRecentApp)
```

**Method**:

```
Public Sub MnuRecentApp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ApplicantID = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Tag.ToString
    frmApplicantEdit.Show()
End Sub
```

`mnuApplicantS` is a `ToolStrip` control in my example. If you could clarify what `mnuApplicatS` is in your application I might be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Hi, Also a ToolStrip menu item. Changed my code to match yours, but still doesn't work...

Comment: @QSTrain that is strange. I had the ability to test this code before supplying it to you and it worked for me. Have you copied the code like for like? Might be worth creating a brand new project and just using my code to see if it works rather than amending yours.

Comment: Hey Jinx, I tried copying your code to the main form on a button's on-click. In there Intellisense / autocomplete doesn't give me an items option (i.e Items is not a member of mnuApplicantS - hence it doesn't do anything. Very Odd, 'cause with your code it adds a menu item...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This line:

```
frmMain.mnuApplicantS.DropDownItems.Add(tlRecentApp.ToString)
```

Should read:

```
frmMain.mnuApplicantS.DropDownItems.Add(tlRecentApp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just In case anyone else has this problem.
I had an instance where it seemed my item click event was not firing.
It turned out I had removed the handler too early (it was dynamic menu).
I had removed the handler in the closed event of the Parent Menu (not kept open). It seems that parent close event is fired before the click event of the item is considered.